# Android - load photo from uri

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-glide

I'm trying to upload the image to imageview via Uri it doesn't work.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/data/user/0/com.maksu.aquarium/cache/cropped6681458112782885202.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

I get the above error. When I check, I see the picture exists.
[image: My photo path]

This is how I upload the photo:

```
     Uri profileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("file:///data/user/0/com.maksu.aquarium/cache/cropped6681458112782885202.jpg"));

Glide.with(this).load(profileUri).into(akvaryumDialogResim);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, **never hardcode paths**. For the purposes of this answer, I will stick with your hardcoded value, but you really need a better way of handling your files. For example, your hard-coded path will be wrong for lots of users.

Second, `file:///data/user/0/com.maksu.aquarium/cache/cropped6681458112782885202.jpg` is not a filesystem path. It is a `Uri`. Android is based on Linux, and its filesystem paths start with `/`. `file://` is a `Uri` scheme, much like how `https://` is a `Uri` scheme used in the URL for this Web page.

So, either use:

```
Uri profileUri = Uri.parse("file:///data/user/0/com.maksu.aquarium/cache/cropped6681458112782885202.jpg");
```

or use:

```
Uri profileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/data/user/0/com.maksu.aquarium/cache/cropped6681458112782885202.jpg"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not already using a hardcode paths. When I save the file to my database, it returns this string. How do I register Uri more accurately in my SQL database?

Comment: I'm using this right now: uri.toString(); and save database...

Comment: The wrong file path is saved when I save it in my own way.

Answer (score 2):

To get access to file in the cache folder, you can use `Context.getCacheDir()` method and not hardcode full path. So, try:

```
Uri profileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(geCacheDir(), "cropped6681458112782885202.jpg"));

Glide.with(this).load(profileUri).into(akvaryumDialogResim);
```

Comment: When saving the file path to my database, I use: uri.toString(); and save database. How do I save?

Comment: The wrong file path is saved when I save it in my own way.